# Nivo Slider Control Nav Animation with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nivo-slider

Basically I want to move the div.nivo-controlNav 125px to the left x times where x is the number of a tags inside it. BUt my code is not working...

The code is from an adult site. Be careful opening the images.

HTML

```
<div style="visibility: visible;" class="nivo-controlNav">
    <a class="nivo-control" rel="0">
      <img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-01.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a class="nivo-control" rel="1"><img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-02.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nivo-control" rel="2"><img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-03.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nivo-control" rel="3"><img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-04.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nivo-control" rel="4">
     <img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-05.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nivo-control" rel="5">
     <img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-06.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nivo-control" rel="6">
     <img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-07.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nivo-control active" rel="7"><img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-08.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nivo-control" rel="8">
     <img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-09.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nivo-control" rel="9">
     <img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-10.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nivo-control" rel="10">
     <img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-11.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nivo-control" rel="11">
     <img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-12.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nivo-control" rel="12">
     <img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/suzan-ferrary-ensaio-dezembro-2014/thumbs/thumbs_curta-temporada-suzana-spartanas-acompanhante-sp-1-13.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var imgs = $(".nivo-controlNav > a").length;
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs; i++) {
    $('.nivo-controlNav').animate({'margin-left': '-125px'}, 500);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're moving the `div.nivo-controlNav` only once, you can move it depending on the amount of images with the following adjustment:

```
var imgs = $(".nivo-controlNav > a").length;
var leftVal;
for (var i = 0; i < imgs; i++) {
  lefVal = i * 125;
  $('.nivo-controlNav').animate({
    'margin-left': -lefVal
  }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. To debug I've placed an alert box with imgs value and it is always = 0. LOoks like the problem is in hte 'var imgs = $(".nivo-controlNav > a").length;'

Comment: @RicardoLimaGonçalves That's strange, which browser you're on? Just created a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yhoacpke/ with some safe dummy images and works for me (Firefox).

Comment: @matthias-h What is happenning is that this div is created by another script and when the document.ready event trigger, it's still loading the images and the div is not there yet. Now my question is, how can I change the code to make it start just after the div is created?

Comment: @matthias-h update: added `setTimeout(function(){ ...}, 20000);` and it's working now. Thank you for your help.